# Isolated points and limit points

Tags: real-analysis

I’m reading a complex analysis textbook, and they do a brief review on real analysis. I’ve attached a screenshot of the page, and highlighted the statement in question. Here is the statement:
“Clearly, for the sequence $\lbrace 1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,...\rbrace$, each natural number is a limit point.”

My question is: since the sequence above is made up of only natural numbers, aren’t each of the numbers in the sequence isolated points, and hence, can’t be limit points? Not every neighbourhood of the point 12, say, contains infinitely many terms of the the sequence $\lbrace 1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,...\rbrace$. Am I missing something? [image]

Comment: There is a distinction between the limit points of a sequence $(f(n))_{n\in \Bbb N}$ and the limit points of the set $\{f(n): n\in \Bbb N\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every neighbourhood of $12$ there exist infinitely many indices where the sequence lies in this neighbourhood.

Comment: @ SmileyCraft: thank you! Just to clarify: even if I take the neighbourhood around the point 12, that only includes the point 12, because the number 12 appears an infinite amount of times in my sequence, it’s a limit point. If the sequence was $\lbrace 1,2,3,4,...\rbrace$ then all the points in the sequence are isolated points, and hence, are not limit points. Correct?

Comment: Well the notion of a limit point has a different meaning depending on whether we consider a set or a sequence, but as far as I know, isolated points only make sense for sets. But if there is a notion of an isolated point of a sequence, then the canonical way to define this would coincide with your claim, so you probably understand it now.